# Monospace font is  not mono spaced in eclipse, why?

Tags: 12.04, fonts, ubuntu-font-family

I recently upgraded to Ubuntu 12.04, and I see that when using eclipse for editing source code, the bold characters displayed with the Monospace font are actually thicker than the non-bold ones. Thus, the Monospace font is actually not mono-space. *(same space for all characters)*

Is this a known issue? Am I missing something?

How do I make it mono-space again?

Comment: Monospace font is indeed thicker when bold than not... that's what bold means.  Do you mean wider?  It's not wider.  If the same word in Monospace take up more of the line when bold versus normal, then perhaps Eclipse is changing the font size on you.

Comment: For example, look at this:  http://cloudfront.omgubuntu.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2011/09/mono.jpg

Comment: Same problem here. As many things are typically screwed after updating, I went through settings (antialiasing, hinting, etc.), but no luck.

Comment: Same problem with droid mono, but others, like bitstream-vera mentioned below (or Liberation Mono) are fine. :/

Comment: I had the same issue with NetBeansIDE (7.4). Monospace font (both bold and normal) displayed fine, until I installed PlayOnLinux and Wine, after which normal versions became narrowed than bolded. The bitstream-vera font mentioned below works fine and is an acceptable workaround.

Comment: The issue here is that the default bold monospace font in 12.04 DOES have a different sized character when using bold vs. non bold for the same size. This is a HUGE issue in Eclipse where bolding is used heavily.

Comment: There is open bug with patch to have option to force font to be monospaced since 2004 ... I guess it's not happening: https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=69253

Answer (score 14):

I'm having a similar problem with Monospace.

As a workaround I've switched to using Bitstream Vera Sans Mono which looks very similar but doesn't have the bold problem.

If you don't have it, you can install it by doing `sudo apt-get install ttf-bitstream-vera`.

Comment: It seems font hinting is broken for the system default monospace fonts (both Monospace and Ubuntu Mono). It appears to work for Bitstream Vera Sans Mono though - thanks for the tip!

Comment: Thanks, that helped alot. As I mentioned above - my problems began after installation of PlayOnLinux and Wine.. which seem to have altered some font configs.

Answer (score 3):

[Monospace](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monospaced_font) refers to all *fixed-width* font. There is also a specific monospaced font called *[Monospace](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monospace_%28Unicode%29)*. Suppose you refer to the specific Monospace font.

I use Monospace font in Libreoffice/Openoffice to align sequences under Ubuntu 12.04. I noticed the same issue: bold Monospace letters are wider than the regular Monospace letters of same size, though they are still monospaced, i.e. fixed-width. See picture

[image]

To find an alternative, have a look at this article [TOP 10 PROGRAMMING FONTS](http://hivelogic.com/articles/top-10-programming-fonts).
I use **Daja vu sans mono** or **Courier New**, which show same width for regular and bold facetypes. At least Inconsolata has the same problem as Monospace.

Answer (score 1):

It appears that the font configuration in 12.04 sets Droid Sans Mono as the default monospace font (see /etc/fonts/conf.d/60-droid-sans-mono-fonts.conf), and as the OP describes, the glyphs in the bold version of this font have a different width than those in the normal version.

To change the system default monospace font, create /etc/fonts/local.conf containing something like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE fontconfig SYSTEM "fonts.dtd">
<fontconfig>
  <alias>
    <family>monospace</family>
    <prefer>
      <family>DejaVu Sans Mono</family>
    </prefer>
  </alias>
</fontconfig>
```

This way, you won't have to remember to change the Eclipse editor font for every workspace you use.

Comment: I had to end up un-bolding everything in Eclipse because this was driving me up the wall. I need to try this though!

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem with OpenJDK 8. The font called "Monospaced" was correctly mapped to "DejaVu Sans Mono" for the "regular"/"plain" style, but something else (probably automatically bolded) for "bold", even if using "DejaVu Sans Mono" directly does the correct thing.

The solution is to fix `~/.java/fonts/*/fcinfo*.properties`. 
It did contain (among many others):

```
monospaced.1.0.file=/usr/share/fonts/truetype/dejavu/DejaVuSansMono.ttf
monospaced.3.0.file=/usr/share/fonts/truetype/dejavu/DejaVuSansMono-Oblique.ttf
```

Everything was fine after changing those to:

```
monospaced.1.0.file=/usr/share/fonts/truetype/dejavu/DejaVuSansMono-Bold.ttf
monospaced.3.0.file=/usr/share/fonts/truetype/dejavu/DejaVuSansMono-BoldOblique.ttf
```